# Naive Bayes Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I found this very helpful video discussing naive bayes classification. I noticed he calculates the probability of a document being positive and not the probability of a word being positive. Is this correct? It was pointed out in the comments, but no response so far from the author.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGKeC2S44Rs

EDIT: I just found this document discussing the same methodology.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html

My new question would be, what if the training data is 50/50? Is there an ideal ratio to use?

Answer (score 1):

The intent is to classify the entire *document* as positive or negative (two classes). The words being present or not - and which words specifically - impact that calculation - but they are not the *target* of the calculation.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me out! What if the training data is 50/50, positive to negative? Is there an ideal ratio?

Comment: @photocode 50/50 is a *good* training ratio - though not often achievable without significant work.  But even with different/somewhat skewed ratios the training may still be achieved.  It is also about the *number* of training instances: with 10/90 and only ten instances ..  But 10/90 with 10 *million* - well that may well be just fine.